# What is the difference between Word: 0 and @in<Word>:(0) in RavenDb

Tags: ravendb

As the title says. What is the difference? I think

> @in< Word>:(0)

is a filter. Where as

> Word:0

searches for a value of 0. But is there a difference is one better than the other?

Am I completely wrong?

I ran a the below in a database and it worked then a ran it a couple more times and it stopped working. Why would that happen? I ran the same code on a duplicated database and it worked.

> @in< Word>:(0)

Answer (score 0):

They both will do effectively the same thing.

`Word: 0` means match on having field `Word` with value `0`.

`@in` does a `IN` search, so you can provide multiple values.

If only one is specified, it is the same as the previous one.